# How can we read text file values in array using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a text file with rows of ID's. Example:

```
ID
1
2
3
```

How can I read this file and store these values in a javascript array, and where should I store my text file?

My current file location is:

```
file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/ash/file/js/UserFile.txt
```

How should I specify the file location in code?

Comment: In a browser or node.js?

Comment: How do you intend to access this text file? Is it a file on the webserver that you can fetch via AJAX, or should the user select the text file from the files on their computer using a file input?

Comment: Users often err asking for a faulty solution instead of explaining the problem the solution is meant to resolve.

Comment: Filee is in the same folder with Javascript file

Comment: GlegL - I want to specify path of my file in javascript code.